# Reversing an IRA contribution?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, contribution

I contributed $6,000 to my IRA last year but turns out I made too much money to be able to deduct IRA contributions.

I've read that I can reverse an IRA contribution if I withdraw the money before April 15th. Is this true? I can't find any IRS publications to support this.

I spoke to my bank and they said if I withdraw the money from my IRA at this point they would report it as an early withdrawal.

Comment: Did you tell the custodian specifically you want to withdraw (also try 'correct' or 'remove') _contributions made in error_? See [pub 590a under 'When Can You Withdraw or Use Assets'](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590a#en_US_2019_publink1000230703) (also downloadable in PDF if you want to show them). PS: if you aren't eligible to deduct trad, you usually aren't eligible to _recharacterize_ to Roth, but if you want you can still make nondeductible contribution to trad and _convert_ to Roth (called 'backdoor Roth') and depending on your other trad/pretax money this _may_ be a good idea.

Comment: But wouldn't the conversion be a taxable event? My fear with the conversion is that I will end up paying double tax (the tax I paid to fund the traditional because it's non tax deductible, and then the tax to convert).

Comment: IRA trad-to-Roth conversion is taxable for the portion that was contributed pretax plus earnings, but not the portion that was contributed posttax/nondeductible, called 'basis'; see form 8606. However, if you only convert part of your trad IRA, this is done pro-rata, with a fraction of the basis left in the IRA where it will be nontaxable when used in a future qualified withdrawal (or another conversion). Hence my reference to 'depending on your other pretax money' (which means deductible contributions and earnings). ...

Comment: ... The 'perfect' case for backdoor is if you have no existing trad/pretax IRA; you open one, make a nondeductible contribution, and convert immeidately; unless your investment was spectacularly good the taxable earnings on a day or two are tiny, and the the nondeductible contribution is nontaxable.

Comment: Dave, that's amazing! Thank you for this! I'll be doing that immediately. If you copy and paste this into the answer I'll happily accept it.